# How many fonts can i use in Qt?

Tags: qt, fonts

Like `setFont(QFont("Helvetica",16,1))`,I want to summerize these fonts.However,I dont't know how many fonts there are.
Is there any guy tell me ? or give me a link. Thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `QFontDatabase` to find out the fonts installed on the system. In particular, check `QFontDatabase::families()`.

Comment: Thank you!@Laurent,you helped me to make progress in Qt!

Comment: @mac.ma You'll do best progress if you'll start using Qt Assistant and it's built in search ;)